# Retrieve values from Java.class List in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I am new to java and JSP. I have found many examples of looping over a returned java class list in a jsp page but none have worked for my situation. The examples do not always show the @page and @taglib values so I have included them because I do not know if there is a specific order required for importing.

I have the following jsp page.

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
 <%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

 <c:set var="cp" value="${pageContext.request.servletContext.contextPath}" scope="request" />

 <html>
      <body>
           <% java.util.List x = new path.to.java.class.method(); %>
           <%=x %>

           <c:forEach items="${x}" var="element">
                <c:out value="${element.id}"/>
           </c:forEach>
      </body>
 </html>
```

The <%=x %> displays comma seperated values like this, path.to.java.class@1234abcd, for the correct number of values returned from the database.  The forEach loop will not display anything.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to set x to a jstl variable and use that variable with the methods of the bean that created the list.

```
 <% java.util.List x = new path.to.java.class.method(); %>
 <c:set var="n" value="<%=x%>"/>

 <c:forEach items="${n}" var="element">
      <c:out value="${element.getId()}"/>
 </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the `c:out` statement to `<c:out value="${element}"/>`?

Comment: Thanks Mike I was able to find the solution.